# How is the synchronized  java keyword implemented?

Tags: java, multithreading

In C#, the `lock` keyword is nice syntax for a `try/catch` block and an instance of `Monitor`.

In Java, what synchronization class is used user the hood of the `synchronized` keyword?

Edit - I did some further poking - looks like it synchronized gets compiled to monitorenter/monitorexit bytecode ops. Is there a class that duplicated these semantics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No class is used - it is a language construct handled by the JVM.

However, Java 5 introduced [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) where you have the [`Lock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface and its multiple implementations. See the linked docs for sample usage.

Comment: I did some further poking - looks like it gets compiled to monitorenter/monitorexit bytecode ops

Answer (score 2):

The `synchronized` keyword causes the entity it modifies to be synchronized with a lock internal to the JVM.  There is no architected class for it, so far as I can recall, and it doesn't necessarily correspond to any specific OS construct.

However, there is a [bytecode construct](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc9.html) for the lock mechanism, used to enter/exit synchronized `{}` blocks.